# Один из графиков отображается как прямая линия

Tags: python, matplotlib

Представленный ниже код - функция для класса FuncAnimation для отрисовки динамически изменяющегося графика. В ys поступает список (проверено). Каждый элемент этого списка тоже список, внутри него три значения. Таким образом получается три графика. Как видно, все три графика отрисовываются, но третий по какой-то причине не меняется (прямая зеленая линия). Так же пример списка, что лежит в ys имеется.

```
def animate(i):
    ys = []
    if stabilizer.flagIsFrameNew:
        if len(stabilizer.tkTransformsList) > 40:
            ys = stabilizer.tkTransformsList[-40:-1]
        else:
            ys = stabilizer.tkTransformsList[:]
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(ys)
        stabilizer.flagIsFrameNew = False
```

[image: Пример графиков]

[image: Пример списка]

Comment: Покажите, что у вас в ys, без этого код вообще бесполезно смотреть. И что в tkTransformsList, ведь вы там его размер проверяете, если код пойдёт в эту ветку у вас в ys будет 40 элементов. Это не вяжется с тем, что вы говорите у вас там три списка. 40 и 3 это не одно и то же

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли, список ys содержит в себе много элементов. Каждый элемент - это список, который содержит в себе 3 значения.
Там ведь есть пример, поглядите.
А ограничение 40 для того, чтобы график не разрастался в бесконечность, а показывал только 40 последних значений

Comment: Добавьте пример ваших данных в сам вопрос в текстовом виде. Ну и дополните код в вопросе до [минимального воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Из того пример данных, который я вижу на картинке, каждое третье значение очень близко к нулю, там величины порядка `1e-5`, вот они и отображаются как сплошная линия возле `0`. Если хотите, чтобы они отображались как-то интереснее, то либо выносите их на отдельный от двух других график, в отдельной картинке, либо можете добавить к графику вторую ось y и рисовать этот третий график согласно этой оси. Вот код для второго варианта со случайными данными, похожими на ваши:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 40
y1 = (np.random.rand(n) - 0.5) * 0.01
y2 = (np.random.rand(n) - 0.5) * 0.02
y3 = (np.random.rand(n) - 0.5) * 1e-5
ys = np.column_stack((y1, y2, y3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(ys)
plt.show()

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(np.column_stack((y1, y2)))
ax2.plot(y3, 'g')

plt.show()
```

График примерно как у вас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

График с теми же данными и дополнительной осью `y`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и правда, я этого не заметил. попробую умножать на 10 е5, спасибо большое !

Comment: Ну, это тоже, конечно, вариант, но на мой взгляд лучше добавить вторую ось, если порядок величины данных имеет какое-то значение. В при добавлении второй оси порядок значений сохранится и будет написан на второй оси. Но так то хозяин-барин, конечно :)